# How can I access to the ViewController which is selected in TabBarViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

```
iOS6
Xcode 4.5.1
Making application for iOS5 or later
using storyboard
```

I want to load an URL when a tabBarItem is clicked.

At targetViewController.m

```
@interface targetViewController ()
@end

@implementation targetViewController
@synthesize webview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self loadingMethod:view.webview];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
(snip)
```

and target2ViewController.m is almost same as targetViewController.m

At customTabBarViewController.m

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar*)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem*)item {
  NSString *str;
  if(item.tag == 0) {
    webview = ((targetViewController *)self.selectedViewController).webview;
    [self myLoadingMethod:webview];
  } else if (item.tag == 1){
    webview = ((target2ViewController *)self.selectedViewController).webview;
    [self myLoadingMethod:webview];
  }
}
```

However this doesn't work well.
When the tarBarItem for targetViewContoller is clicked, the target"2"ViewContoller's webview will load.
and the tabBarItem for target"2"ViewCOntroller is clicked, targetViewContoller's webview will load.

so How can I access to the webview which is included in the ViewController for the cliced tabBarItem?

Comment: Given that when you tap a tabbar item, you present a viewcontroller's view, why don't you just load the url in its `viewDidAppear:` method?

Comment: Sorry for my short explanation. I want to load an url when viewDidApeard and the tabBarItem is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITabBarController` property `selectedViewController` ,which will give you the selected `ViewController`.
In Code you adding `[self myLoadingMethod:wwebview]`; which wrong and it should be [self myLoadingMethod:webview]. Please check.

Comment: Tnank you for your comments. I just mistype only in this site. I wrote right in the actual code.

then I use selectedViewController, but I was not the ViewController but a ViewController which was showed when the tabBarItem has been clicked.

Comment: if you find answer helpful ,please vote up or accept the answer.